# SP 2010 TEXT Function Subtracting 1 hour

Tags: 2010, calendar, calculated-column, date-time

I have a calculated column on a calendar that just formats the start time of an event. I am just using the TEXT function to format the time as `hh:mm` but for some reason the output of the function is always 1 hour before the specified end time. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

**End Time**

[image: End Time]

**Formatted Column of End Time**

[image: Work End Time]

**Work End Time Formula**

[image: Work End Time Formula]

In case you cannot see the screenshot the formula is as follows:

```
 =TEXT([End Time],"hh:mm AM/PM")
```

**UPDATE**

This is definitely an issue with End Time. Every time I open an event to edit it, End Time is subtracted by 1 hour. I have no idea what is causing this.

Comment: Not able to reproduce. Check your Regional Settings/Timezone settings. Also add End Time to the view to make sure its not using any Day Light Savings.

Comment: Okay it definitely looks like End Time is subtracting 1 hr from whatever is input. Does that mean it is using Day Light Savings time? If so, how can I turn this off?